# sed replace string with a single quote inside of it

Tags: bash, ssh, sed, escaping

I want to modify a script that exists on a remote host using a bash script.

My bash script has a command like this to run a sed command on the remote host:

```
ssh user@domain.com "some_command"
```

There is a file called config.php that I want to modify with a sed command.

I want to replace a string like this

```
'debug' => true
```

with this

```
'debug' => false
```

The sed command (that's not working) is something like this:

```
sed 's/'debug'->true/'debug'=>false/g' config.php > newconfig.php
```

What is the correct sed command to use, and how do I also get it to correctly escape all the characters inside the ssh " " command?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$ sed -r "s@('debug'\s*=>\s*).*@\1false@" file
'debug' => false
```

So :

```
ssh user@host<<'EOF'
sed -i -r "s@('debug'\s*=>\s*).*@\1false@" /PATH/TO/config.php
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a little test on my servers and this seemed to work. You could try using double quotes within the sed command but escape them.

```
ssh user@domain.com "sed \"s/'debug' => true/'debug' => false/g\" /path/to/config.php > /path/to/newconfig.php"
```